# Code Javascript to auto run a slider on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I make this so 5 seconds after the page loads it does the same as using the checkbox? We don't need the checkbox function anymore and just need the slider to start on its' own when the page is opened.

Do you think it's possible? Thanks!!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('#checkbox').change(function(){
setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: it's possible. You're welcome.

Comment: Just take the `setInterval()` out of the change event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
 }, 3000);
});
```

Use setTimeout if you want it to run just once:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Use setInterval if you want it to run repeatedly
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Comment: W3Schools is notoriously bad for documentation. Please link to a better site such as MDN -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: He doesn't say anything about it only running once.  And please don't quote w3schools....  http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Corrected the answer. Negging it for w3schools link, really? It is often simpler for newbies and Google search ranks it higher than mozilla docs!